# How do I change the resolution of the kinect?

Tags: kinect, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What tools are available for changing the resolution of the kinect?

This is a repost from ros-users: https://code.ros.org/lurker/thread/20110221.054716.d9dc88ae.en.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9140/how-do-i-change-the-resolution-of-the-kinect?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use dynamic reconfigure:

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1